# Trigger to update a table on update of another table when multiple records meet a condition

Tags: triggers, subquery, case

I have 2 tables: route and route_details.

route_details simply contains shipment_id,route_id, and active state 1 or 0.

A shipment_id can only be associated to a single route_id.

When the route_details table gets updated based on a single shipment active state set to 0 I want a trigger that will update route and set active to 0 only if all records for that route_id in the route_details table are inactive (0)

I have tried a nested subquery with a case statement and an if statement but I can't quite figure out the logic...

I’ve gotten to this point:

CREATE TRIGGER inactive_route
AFTER UPDATE
ON route_details FOR EACH ROW
select if(active is null,route_id,0)  from route_details where route_id in (
select route_id from route_details  where shipment_id=107
) and active = OLD.active

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually figured this out myself - using where not exists:
CREATE TRIGGER route_inactive
AFTER UPDATE ON route_details
FOR EACH ROW update route
SET `active` = 'N' where route_id = (
select route_id from route_details where not exists (select route_id from route_details where route_id in (
select route_id from route_details  where shipment_id=OLD.shipment_id
) and `active` = 'Y') )